How can I debug a Java process that exits without an error?
I launch a jar with the latest version of OpenJDK 8:
 /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/bin/java -verbose -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2"   -cp "/applis/com/myapp/:/applis/com/myapp/myapp.jar"  com.myapp.AppLauncher
...
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException from /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter from /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$IdentityHashMapIterator from /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeyIterator from /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/jre/lib/rt.jar]
$ echo $?
0
$ /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_412"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_412-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.412-b08, mixed mode)

The process stops without an error message and the exit code is 0.
On another machine (same OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo), same version of jdk , same jar), the process keeps on running. I can't work out what makes the java process stop.
The selinux is set to permissive on both machines:
$sudo getenforce
Permissive

In the folder /applis/com/myapp,  there is only the jar file + a myapp.properties file.  This file contains only name of servers.  The file has not been modified. It is the same in both machines. Also, on the machine where it fails, the app manages to start with an old version of oracle jdk
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
To summarize:
Machine 1  |  Fails with openjdk-1.8.0_412  | Succeeds with JSE 1.8.0_101-b13
Machine2  | Succeeds with both openjdk-1.8.0_412  and JSE 1.8.0_101-b13
Same OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

Are you sure that you want to specify an absolute path in the classpath? Why do you specify the folder where the jar lies in and the jar itself in the classpath? Any reason why you don't put enough configuration into your JAR file to run it with -jar ?

Set suspend=y and this.

@cyberbrain : that was the indication provided by the team who owns the  jar. I do not have the answer unfortunately. It is a legacy jar and the developers are no longer around. I would have to dig into the code and understand the project.

@ElliottFrisch Thanks for the hint. I will try these options although I will have to have access to the code.

"provided by the team who owns the jar" ?? So are there any other files in that folder /applis/com/myapp/ on the machine where it works? Please add the answer to your question.

usual way to start an executable JAR: /opt/jdk/jdk8u412-b08/bin/java -verbose -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2"   -jar "/applis/com/myapp/myapp.jar"

@cyberbrain  I added the infos.  There is a properties file in that folder. however it is identicatl in both VM. Also, the app manages to start on an old  version of oracle jdk.  I suspect the problem to come from a configuration of the VM

since you have an extra property about TLS, you could check the truststores of a VM where it is running with the one where it doesn't work. You can use the keytool of java to do that. You find the truststore usually in the lib/security/cacerts  file of your VM, default password is changeit.

I checked the truststore. Both machines use the same truststore. On the VM where openjdk8-422 does not manage to launch the app, I tried using Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_411-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.411-b09, mixed mode).  I manage to launch the application with that version of java. So it seems there is a problem with this VM and openjdk8.  With the other VM, I can launch the app with any version of jdk (java se or openjdk8 and even openjdk11).

This is an answer that does not explain how to debug the java.  @elliotfrish and @cyberbrain did give enough explanations about that
Here is an explanation about why the openjdk 8 failed whereas the code was running fine on oracle jdk 8. The fact that I managed to launch the jar with openjdk8 on another VM also confirmed the issue was not on the jar itself but on the conf of the VM.
There was actually a font library missing on the VM.
The installation of fontconfig.x86_64 and its dependencies solved the issue.

maybe it will be more helpful to include what (exactly) you have done, eventually including how the problem can be identified

I wanted to include the log but I do not have it anymore. An error message appears more clearly when you launch directly the java -jar  command.  It referred to svg font errors.  This error was not visible when launching the command with -cp option.
